# Summing the following two series

Tags: calculus, summation

I have encountered the following two sums:

\begin{equation}
S_1(\alpha, N) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{N-1} \dfrac{e^{i\alpha \sin(\phi_j/2)}}{\sin^k(\phi_j/2)}, \quad S_2(\alpha, N) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{N-1} \dfrac{e^{i\alpha \sin(\phi_j/2)} \cos(\phi_j)}{\sin^k(\phi_j/2)},
\end{equation}

where $1\le k\le3$, and $\phi_j = \frac{2 \pi j }{N}$.

I tried to replace sums with integrals, but in this case a change of variable is required to $x=\sin(\phi_j/2)$ or $x=\cos(\phi_j/2)$, and things like $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ appear, which is nasty to have.

Any good ideas of how to calculate analytically these types of sums? (Though I have no guarantee that it is possible to do precisely, even some approximations will be good!)

Comment: It seem there will be the divergency, if we switch to integration: at $x\to0$ there will be $\int_0\frac{1}{x^k}dx\to\infty$ ( $k\in(1,3)$). I'm not sure that we can switch from the sum to the integral - at small $j$ $S\sim\sum_{j\geq1}\frac{N^k}{\pi^k{j}^k}\sim{N}^k$

Comment: Hi, @Svyatoslav. Yeah, I definitely agree with you that $x^{k}$ with $k<-1$ has a divergent integral for the considered domain. However, when going from a discrete sum to an integral, there is also an "error" term, coming from the Euler-Maclaurin formula. So, I really believe that the error term also has a divergent part, and these two will cancel each other. As they have to, as the original finite sum is, clearly, a convergent one. The question is rather about a general "trick" to even approach these kinds of integrals, as they appear for physical problems with specific symmetries.

Comment: I agree with you - the initial sum converges. My point was that in some cases we cannot switch to integration and have to consider a separate terms of the sum (at least, some of them). The physical example that comes to my mind is Bose-Einstein condensation - where we have to consider main and second levels, and statistical sum is mainly determined by them (contribution of other levels is much smaller and can be considered through integration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some physical rationale (these series appear in a physical problem), I was able to obtain a fairly good approximation for specific linear combinations of the sums above in the limit $N \to \infty$. I am too lazy to prove this mathematically, so I will give away the answer and the numerical check. Let us define the $6$ following sums:

\begin{eqnarray}
\Sigma_1(\alpha, N) = \dfrac{1}{4} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{N-1} \dfrac{1+\cos(\phi_j)}{\alpha \sin(\phi_j/2)} e^{i \alpha \sin(\phi_j/2)}, \quad \tilde{\Sigma}_1(\alpha, N) = \dfrac{\rm{Li}_1(e^{i \alpha \sin(\phi_1/2)})}{\alpha \sin(\phi_1/2)}; \nonumber\\
\Sigma_2(\alpha, N) = \dfrac{1}{4} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{N-1} \dfrac{3-\cos(\phi_j)}{(\alpha \sin(\phi_j/2))^2} e^{i \alpha \sin(\phi_j/2)}, \quad \tilde{\Sigma}_2(\alpha, N) = \dfrac{\rm{Li}_2(e^{i \alpha \sin(\phi_1/2)})}{(\alpha \sin(\phi_1/2))^2}; \nonumber\\
\Sigma_3(\alpha, N) = \dfrac{1}{4} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{N-1} \dfrac{-3+\cos(\phi_j)}{(\alpha \sin(\phi_j/2))^3} e^{i \alpha \sin(\phi_j/2)}, \quad \tilde{\Sigma}_3(\alpha, N) = - \dfrac{\rm{Li}_3(e^{i \alpha \sin(\phi_1/2)})}{(\alpha \sin(\phi_1/2))^3}.
\end{eqnarray}

In the above $\rm{Li}_s(z)$ is a polylogarithm special function.

My claim is that for sufficiently large $N$, $\Sigma_j(\alpha,N)\to\tilde{\Sigma}_j(\alpha, N)$. In order to make it illustrative, let us plot these sums as functions of $\alpha$, for some big $N$.

[[image: Sum <span class=]$\Sigma_1$ for N=100" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsPLz.png)
[[image: Sum <span class=]$\Sigma_2$ for N=100" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SH3n.png)
[[image: Sum <span class=]$\Sigma_3$ for N=100" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHZeT.png)
[[image: Sum <span class=]$\Sigma_1$ for N=10000" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hagn.png)

A couple of comments on these pictures:

- Sums $\Sigma_2, \Sigma_3$ converge to their limiting values already for $N\sim 100$ nicely (see figures 2, 3 above).
- The worst sum is $\Sigma_1$ bcoz of $1/(\alpha \sin(\phi_j/2))$ term. One needs to take $N\sim 10^{3}-10^{4}$ to achieve a convincing level of convergence (compare figures 1, and 4 above).
- Sum $\tilde{\Sigma}_1$ diverges each time $\alpha \sin(\phi_1/2) = 2\pi m$, where $m$ is some integer. This condition corresponds to what is called Bragg resonance in physics (one can see a couple of these peaks in figures 1, 4 above). This happens because in this case $\rm{Li}_1(1) = \zeta(1) = \infty$, where $\zeta(z)$ is the Riemann zeta-function.

**Thank you for attention!**